# Перенаправление трафика с роутера на необходимый пк

Tags: сеть, lan

Сразу скажу, что в данной теме я и не очень то разбираюсь, если не совсем не разбираюсь...

У меня имеется роутер, к которому подключен пк, и всё это дело находится в домашней сети. Я, конечно, понимаю, что для все этих нужд есть хостинг ресурсы, но на этом моё любопытство не останавливается. Моя задача состоит в том, чтобы при переходе из разных сетей на внешний ip моего роутера (если можно так сказать) запросившему отдавалась та или иная логика, которая должна отдаваться моим пк (опять же, если можно так сказать). В различных статьях я уже успел прочитать про какие-то балансировщики или проброс портов: что на роутер приходит трафик, и тот в свою очередь не знает, что с ним делать (А Я ЗНАЮ! отправлять его на мой пк! (: ).

Насчет хостинговых ресурсов. Там предоставляется внешний ip, который сразу перенаправляет на сервер и нет никаких проблем (кто до сих пор не понял, о чем это я).

Так вот, не могли бы вы, пожалуйста, объяснить мне или подкинуть реально стоящих статей на эту тему.

Comment: Собственно, купить внешний ip у провайдера и прописать проброс портов в настройках роутера — больше ничего и не нужно

Comment: @andreymal мне говорили, что статический ip необязателен

Comment: Статический необязателен, а внешний обязателен

Comment: @andreymal внешний ip и так предоставляется провайдером. Либо я чего то не понимаю

Comment: Значит порты пробросить и всё

Comment: @andreymal перехожу на адрес шлюза и там нет такой функции, как Port Forwarding

Comment: Ну тут нам уже нечего добавить, читайте инструкцию к своему роутеру (если функция проброса портов в нём вообще есть)

Comment: @andreymal хорошо, понял

Comment: @USER1111, добавлю, что в морде роутера соответствующие разделы могут также называться «virtual servers» или «firewall»...

Comment: @Fat-Zer ну это у меня больше не роутер был, а модем. Ну а так спасибо, буду внимателен по данному поводу

Comment: @andreymal Еще раз, здравствуйте, добрался до нормального роутера, настроил правила для проброса портов и браундмауэра на TCP/80, но из интернета так и не удается подключиться :( подключаюсь по ip, который выдает сервис 2ip (может так и нельзя, конечно)

Comment: @USER1111 во-первых, а у вас вообще есть что-нибудь, что принимает соединения на порту 80? Во-вторых, если всё-таки есть, попробуйте отключить брандмауэр — возможно, именно он ограничивает соединения. Если отключение брандмауэра поможет, нужно будет включить его обратно (сидеть с отключенным небезопасно) и добавить в его настройках разрешение подключения к порту 80

Comment: @andreymal написал простенький код, который выводит ip стороны подключения, а брадмауэр изначально стоял на 80 порту, ну и без него тоже запускал